# Can someone help me understand Guava CacheLoader?

Tags: caching, guava

I'm new to Google's Guava library and am interested in Guava's Caching package. Currently I have version 10.0.1 downloaded. After reviewing the documentation, the JUnit tests source code and even after searching google extensively, I still can't figure out how to use the Caching package. The documentation is very short, as if it was written for someone who has been using Guava's library not for a newbie like me. I just wish there are more real world examples on how to use Caching package propertly.

Let say I want to build a cache of 10 non expiring items with Least Recently Used (LRU) eviction method. So from the example found in the api, I build my code like the following:

```
Cache<String, String> mycache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(10)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
         public String load(String key) throws Exception {
           return something; // ?????
         }
       });
```

Since the CacheLoader is required, I have to include it in the build method of CacheBuilder. But I don't know how to return the proper value from mycache.

To add item to mycache, I use the following code:

```
mycache.asMap().put("key123", "value123");
```

To get item from mycache, I use this method:

```
mycache.get("key123")
```

The get method will always return whatever value I returned from CacheLoader's load method instead of getting the value from mycache. Could someone kindly tell me what I missed?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Guava's `Cache` type is generally intended to be used as a *computing* cache. You don't usually add values to it manually. Rather, you tell it how to load the expensive to calculate value for a key by giving it a `CacheLoader` that contains the necessary code.

A typical example is loading a value from a database or doing an expensive calculation.

```
private final FooDatabase fooDatabase = ...;

private final LoadingCache<Long, Foo> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(10)
    .build(new CacheLoader<Long, Foo>() {
      public Foo load(Long id) {
        return fooDatabase.getFoo(id);
      }
    });

public Foo getFoo(long id) {
  // never need to manually put a Foo in... will be loaded from DB if needed
  return cache.getUnchecked(id);
}
```

Also, I tried the example you gave and `mycache.get("key123")` returned `"value123"` as expected.

Comment: OP, I'd be interested to know how we can tweak the example in http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html so it would have been clearer?

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. This example should be on the documentation. Not sure how to make the documentation clearer, a real world example will always be better for a noob like me.

Comment: @user997496: `CacheBuilder`'s documentation has a similar example, except it uses "creating an expensive graph" based on the key rather than "loading a value from a database" as the operation that the `CacheLoader` does.

Comment: The part where ColinD says "never need to manually put a Foo in... will be loaded from DB if needed" really hit my G spot.

Comment: Actually the code above should read `LoadingCache` and not `Cache`, which doesn't have a `get(key)` method.

Comment: @CedricBeust: At the time I wrote this, there was no `LoadingCache` and all `Cache`s were loading caches. I've updated it.

Comment: this is called memoization, to memoize, <- helping googlers